# how to use Fuzzy match query with should or bool in elasticsearch-php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

i have a query which searches for brand name in an index ,i want to compensate for spelling errors by using fuzzy match,but bool doesn't support fuzzy ,any help?

```
 [
    'query' => [
        "bool"=>[
            "should"=>$shouldBrandArray 
            ]
        ],
        'size'=>2
    ]
```

Comment: Bool query in essence is a placeholder for combining other queries, so try sticking your match query inside a must clause

Comment: can you give me a basic example?

Comment: Here you go https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html